# Test environment for the google drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

How to test safely an app that reads and writes to Google Drive using the API?

I created an app that runs on a server, that basically copies a template google doc to another directory, and then edits this new file.

In order to do that I:

- created a service account,
- delegated domain-wide authority to this service account
  (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority),

Then the app impersonates a user of the domain (always the same user) to access the API resources.

This app works, but it has 2 problems:

- the service account has access to too many things. Ideally, I'd like it to have RW access to one folder only,
- I'd like to create test credentials that would have access to another specific folder only, or even better, another drive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Drive does not have permissions based on folders. The closest you can get is by creating an additional Service Account and then share the folder(s) to that SA.

Comment: I tried with the service account that I created for my project, using its email address (xxxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com), but it's not recognized as being part of our organization and I get this error:

"Sorry, an item cannot be shared outside of XXXXXXX."

Also I'd like to not change our sharing settings for the whole organization

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the sharing setting for just one organisational unit,doing that all the folders whose owners are part of that OU will be able to share it outside or your domain making that the SA have only access to those folders.